# Probability distribution of binomial variable multiplied by a uniform variable

Tags: probability-distributions, uniform-distribution, binomial-distribution

> Given is a binomial variable with success rate $p$, and on success, you receive anywhere between $X_1$ and $X_2$ dollars, uniformly distributed. On failure, you receive nothing.

From what I've gathered, the sum of multiple uniform variables would be an *Irwin-Hall distribution* which approximates a normal distribution in the limit, but this case is a bit different.

> Question: What would be the Probability Mass Function (PMF) of the total amount of money you receive after $N$ trials?

Approximations could be acceptable here (e.g. maybe it's similar to summing $N\cdot p$ normal variables which results in a normal distribution; or maybe a binomial multiplied by the average of $X_1$ and $X_2$.)

P.S.: I should clarify that I plan to use an existing Java library or code my own distribution myself to calculate the PMF, so if the resulting distribution is very complicated but can be approximated well by a simpler distribution, that would be preferred.

Comment: Let see if I understand this correctly. Let $N\sim \mathcal{B}(n,p)$ be a Binomial distributed random variable and let $Y_N = \sum_{i=1}^N U_i$ where $U_i\sim \mathcal{U}(x_1, x_2)$. You are interested in the distribution of $Y_N$?

Comment: Yes, I believe this and the other answer both capture the idea: the distribution of summing N identical uniform variables dependent on first succeeding in N Bernoulli trials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:**  Added an exact solution at the end.

For $N=1$ we want to know something about $Y=U*X$ where $U$ has a uniform distribution on $(x_1, x_2)$ and $X$ has a Bernoulli distribution with probability $p$.

We have a mixture distribution in that there is a probability mass of $1-p$ at zero and a "uniform" distribution on $(x_1,x_2)$.  The $k$-th moment of that distribution is

$$m_k=\int_{x_1}^{x_2} \frac{p x^k}{x_2-x_1} \, dx+0^k p = \frac{p \left(x_2^{k+1}-x_1^{k+1}\right)}{(k+1) (x_2-x_1)}$$

The moment generating function for a single observation is

$$\text{mgf}=1+\sum _{m=1}^{\infty } \frac{t^m p \left(x_2^{m+1}-x_1^{m+1}\right)}{m! (m+1) (x_2-x_1)}$$

So for the sum of $n$ observations the moment generating function is $\text{mgf}^{~n}$.  The mean and variance of the sum of these random variables are found from the moment generating function:

$$\mu=\frac{1}{2} n p (x_1+x_2)$$
$$\sigma^2=\frac{1}{12} n p \left((4-3 p) x_1^2+(4-6 p) x_1 x_2+(4-3 p) x_2^2\right)$$

Depending on the values of $n$ and $p$, one might be able to use the above mean and variance with a normal approximation.

**Exact solution**

If you are able to switch to *Mathematica*, then for samples sizes at least up to $n=20$ finding the exact distribution is doable.  One just sums the products of the probability of obtaining $k$ successes and the density for the generalized Irwin-Hall distribution with sample size $k$.

There is a probability of $(1-p)^n$ at zero.  The "density" part of the distribution is found with the following code (using a specific example):

```
n = 10;
p = 1/4;
x1 = 10;
x2 = 25;
pdf = Sum[Binomial[n, k] p^k (1 - p)^(n - k) PDF[UniformSumDistribution[k, {x1, x2}], y],
  {k, 1, n}];

Plot[pdf, {y, 0, 250}, Exclusions -> None]
```

[image: "pdf"]

Alternatively, we can plot the cdf which does exist.

```
Plot[((1 - p)^n) + Integrate[pdf, {y, 0, yy}], {yy, 0, 250}, Frame -> True]
```

[image: cdf]

Comment: Thanks! Would a better question be: What is the "limit behavior" of $Y$ as $n$ becomes very large?


Let's specify $X1$ = 10 and $X2$ = 25 for the purposes of this question. Let $p$ be relatively low, roughly 1/100. 


If $X1$ and $X2$ are rather close together in comparison to their magnitudes, then surely this approaches a binomial distribution, scaled by the average of $X1$ and $X2$. If the Xs are farther apart, however, I'm not sure what that would look like.

Comment: Note: I say "let $p$ be relatively low", because as $p$ approaches one, the distribution must approach the shape of the *Irwin-Hall distribution*.

Comment: @Mr.P I changed my response because I realized that you really wanted a Bernoulli random variable rather than a binomial random variable.

Comment: This looks fantastic, thank you so much! The limit behavior I described in words above looks like it works perfectly. 

As $x1$ and $x2$ approach one another, we get a mean of $x n p$, and variance $x^2 n p (1-p)$, which looks like a scaled binomial as expected. 

As $p$ approaches 1, we get a mean of $n (x1 + x2)/2$, which makes perfect sense as the average of a sum of uniform distributions, and variance $1/12 * n (x2 - x1)^2$, which does indeed line up exactly with an Irwin-Hall distribution when taking $x2 = 1$ and $x1 = 0$.

Comment: I'm going to test this numerically on some examples and see how good the approximation is. I am wondering whether any skewness term is necessary, but I think it may be close enough for my purposes.

Comment: I think the fit (using a normal approximation using the mean and variance) will mainly depend on the sample size.  If $n<10$, then there is more than skewness to consider.

Comment: Good point. I have another idea for computing the distribution exactly: If we have received $Z$ dollars, we know that somewhere between $ceiling(Z / X2)$ and $floor(Z / X1)$ Bernoulli trials were successful. So, the overall cumulative probability $P(z <= Z)$ would equal the sum from S = $ceiling(Z / X2)$ to $floor(Z / X1)$ of $Binom(N, p)(s = S) * IrwinHall(N)(s <= S)$. The IrwinHall part needs some rescaling from range $[0,1]$ to $[x1, x1]$, but you get the idea. And not sure how to format the math but close enough.

Comment: Can you share a sense of what values of sample size ($N$), $X_1$, and $X_2$ might be?  Getting an exact distribution for $N<10$ for general $p$, $X_1$, and $X_2$ is doable but will look very messy.  And likely some simplification would occur if $X_2-X_1=1$.

Comment: $X1$ and $X2$ are always integers, with $X1$ having a range of roughly $[0, 1e6]$ and $X2$ having a range of roughly $[0, 2e6]$. They are usually within 1 order of magnitude of one another, but it's also common that $X1 = 0$ while $X2$ is very large. $N$ has a range of roughly $[0, 1e5].

Comment: Very interesting graphs for your exact solution! It's much more chaotic than I expected. What I'm thinking is that the exact solution is possible for low values of $N$, and one or more approximations could be made for high values of $N$ (or maybe high values of $N * p$). As $N*p$ increases to greater than ~5, the UniformSumDistribution should be very closely approximated by a normal distribution. I'm also thinking as $N*p$ increases further, maybe to $> 20$, I could just use a single normal distribution with the mean/variance you derived. I'm still working on trying out different thresholds